# AngularJS : $http success query inside extended factory not updating variables

Tags: angularjs

I'm doing a factory like this :
(simplified version)

```
module.factory("$list", function($http, $env) {
  var service =  function() {
    this.items = [];
    this.count = 0;

    this.updateCount = function() {
      var self = this;
      $http.head($env.host + '/path/to/resource')
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        self.count = headers()['x-total-count']
      });
    };
  };
  updateCount(); //this doesn't update the count value

  return service;
});
```

Then i'm using it to extend a model factory :

```
module.factory("Model", function($resource, $http, $list, $env) {
  angular.extend(Model, $resource(
    $env.host + '/base/path/:id',
    {id: "@id"},
    { }
  ));
  angular.extend(Model, $list);
  Model.updateCount(); // this updates the count value
};
```

And then my controller is using it :

```
angular.module('my_module').controller('MyController', function($scope, Model){
  $scope.model = Model;
}
```

I can use all the `$resource` functions, but the second extend of `$list` return a count not updated after the success, and doesn't seem to watch it.

How can I ensure that my $list extend variables are properly updated on success and seen within the main factory ?

**UPDATE 1 :**

I've updated the `$list` factory.

The only way to have the count value dynamically updated and watched is by calling the `count()` method within the extended factory, not in the `$list` factory. I don't know why it doesn't work within the `$list` factory.

Comment: Are you getting any console error

Comment: No error, i'm getting the initial value for count (ie 0), and i know the request enter the success block and updates the count variable, but it's not updated later inside the final controller and in the view

Comment: I think when you are using  new Model() it instantiate again and makes it empty and so the variables not get updates. Not sure

Comment: use `$scope.model = Model;` don't instantiate service..

Comment: It stills show the default value of 0, the success of the $http query update the value in the instance, but it's not visible from the controller nor the view

Comment: are you sure this is getting called and returning value?

Comment: @pankajparkar i've updated regarding what you said and some new tests from my side.

Comment: @Sylver did you able to find any way to do this ?

Comment: @pankajparkar nope, i'm still using the `Model.updateCount()` when extending `Model` with `$list` as stated in the original post. It's not ideal to have this repeat everywhere, but i didn't dig further for the moment.

Comment: @Sylver  could you give me a plunkr/fiddle of the same..so that i can play with it..\